# How to show this empirical risk minimization problem has a specific optimum?

Tags: convex-optimization

I'm trying to show for general regularized empirical risk minimization problem that the minimizing $w$ for
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \textrm{loss}(w^T y_i,x_i) + \mu \lVert{w\rVert}^2, $$
 where the loss function is convex in the first argument and $w$ and each $y_i$ is a vector in $R^d$,

has the form $w_* = \alpha^T y$ for some $n$-dimensional vector $\alpha$. I've been able to show this is true for the case that we have the least-squares problem but I don't know how one can go about a generalization. Also will $w_*$ have the form $\alpha^T y$ if the loss function is not convex?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you're asking for? It's not clear now.

Comment: I'm trying to show that $w_* = a^T y = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i y_i$ for some $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ if the loss function is convex.

Comment: This does not depend on $x_i$'s. Is that meaningful?

Comment: Eh I don't know why it would be. I thought about that for a while.

Comment: Actually, it would be rather weird if the solution did not depend on $x_i$'s. Is your question related with the Support Vector Machine (SVM) theory?

Comment: Yes it is indeed.

Comment: Then look at the SVM's solution. You will find out what the problem is..